# How to include php file using Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, include

I have that div:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

and I want to include inside PHP file using jQuery.

I try with this, but doesn't work:

```
var about_me = "<?php include('php/about_me.php') ?>"

$('$content').click(function(){
 $('#content').text(about_me);
});
```

This returns me PHP code like a string?

Answer (score 17):

You could use [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$("#content").load('/about_me.php');
```

Comment: Yes, this works!
If I have some questions, I will write here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is it a .php file? IF it's a .js or .html file, Apache (or whatever webserver you're using) won't interpret it as a PHP file and won't include the relevant file.

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple way that you can do it.
Just do it.

just put the file name in **.load** function

```
$(function(){  $("#includedContent").load("header.php"); });
```