# How to include php file using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I already visited this link,

[How to include php file using Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652328/how-to-include-php-file-using-jquery)

but when I m trying it in my code, its not working. What could be the issue?

**index file**

```
<div id="content">Hi</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var about_me = "<?php include('del.php') ?>"
$('$content').click(function(){
    $('#content').load(about_me);
});
</script>
```

**del.php**

```
<?php
echo "hi again";
?>
```

Comment: @MartinStoyanov Tried it. Not Working :(

Comment: As javascript runs on the client, and php should have to be ran on the server, it simply will not work this way.

What I do in such a situation is to include the del.php in a container that only becomes visible when the click happens.

Comment: I tried this line `$('$content').ready(function(){` instead of  `$('$content').click(function(){`
Still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure you include the jQuery library.

Second, don't use `include` as it isn't necessary. You will just load the file via jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var about_me = "del.php";
    $('#content').click(function(){
        $('#content').load(about_me);
    });
});
</script>
```

NOTE: You have a typo in your selector `$content` should be `#content` to make it clickable. I have also included a document ready function in the event your script is at the top of the page, instead of the bottom.

Comment: Not Working :-(

Comment: By "not working" what do you mean? Are there any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: @AjinkyaRathod - "Not working" isn't that helpful. What happens? Check the console for errors and/or the network tab in your browsers developer tools to check if it makes a request at all. Btw, I would recommend putting you js in `$(function () {   ...your js goes here... });` to make sure that the DOM have finished loading when it's executed. [Read more in the manual](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: @AjinkyaRathod is the script at the top or the bottom of your page? If it is at the top you will need to include it in a document ready handler.

Comment: @AjinkyaRathod have you included the jQuery library in your project?

Comment: Jay Blanchard.  I made such a silly mistake. Wasted hours for this :-( I forget to include the jquery libraries.Thank you very much  :-)

Answer (score 0):

[**.load()**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) accepts url (type string) as first parameter, not a php code.

Try to change it from:
`var about_me = "<?php include('del.php') ?>"`

To: `var about_me = "/del.php"`

**EDIT:** You have a typo in your event listener's selector, should be `$('#content').click()` instead of `$('$content').click()`

Comment: Nope. Not Woking in either cases

Comment: Updated, you had a typo.