# How to include php with JQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have been struggling with this for a while now.

What I found is this:

```
<div id="include"></div>
        <script>
$(function(){
    $("#include").load("/test.php");
});
    </script>
```

This does work when in test.php is a simple code like:

```
<?php echo 'echo world'; ?>
```

But it doesn't work when I want to grab Wordpress variables.

```
<?php   $current_user_id =  $current_user->ID;
echo $current_user_id; ?>
```

There's nothing outputed. No error. Just a blank.

It's like it doesn't send the variables to the test.php. So test.php doesn't  echo values filled. When I use `<?php include 'test.php';?>` it does fill the variables and works as I wanted.

So basically, `.load` simply loads the file.

But I want `<?php include;?>` to be executed instead of `.load`.

When I use `<?php include;?>` I can grab variables, which I need.

Is there other command instead of .load to do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652328/how-to-include-php-file-using-jquery this answer your question?

Comment: No it doesn't. As I said .load doesn't include php. It only loads. I have already seen this thread.

Comment: Please elaborate on “doesn’t work”. With full PHP error reporting turned on, as well as WP_DEBUG on, do you see an error? When you are loading your PHP file, is there code before your first usage of `$current_user` that boots WordPress, since calling a PHP manually won’t boot it for you?

Comment: Sorry. There's nothing outputed. No error. Just a blank. It's like it doesn't send the variables to the test.php. So test.php output a blank. When I use `<?php include 'test.php';?>` it does fill the variables and works as I wanted.

Comment: No other code is used before my usage of `$current_user`. All I do now is test to see if I can even fill the variables using JQuery. Which I'm unsuccessful so far.

Comment: You will need to include the basic WP loader into your own script then, for something like this to work - see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/245364/how-can-i-call-wordpress-core-functions-in-external-scripts

Comment: It worked! Thanks CBroe. Please write as an answer, so I could upvote and accept.